# How to search using textDidChange in SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I have created a search bar and am using this function:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    getAlamoWithSearchText(withOffsetValue: 0)
    print("Here it is: \(posts.count)")
}
```

How can I implement a timer so it only changes after the user has stopped typing for 1 second?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to implement this. One of them is to add a timer in class scope. Then invalidate the timer in the textDidChange delegate method. Below this add a statement to schedule the method call with the "repeat" param as false.

In the called method, call your API to search the elements.

Comment: Could you go more in depth and maybe write out how to do this?

Comment: var timer = timer() in class body outside any method , preferred above viewdidload() then add those 2 statements in textdidchange() timer.invalidate()    
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(callSearchApi), userInfo: nil, repeats: false).

Comment: @JitendraTnwar, I tried to edit this by turning you comment into code but it wasn't easy. Please - a good answer (which this appears to be) should be full! Turn you comment into working code. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think code is necessary here. The explanation is clear and concise. Its original form just needs some grammatical help, which is easy to provide.